# mobile app for interacting with camera with html5?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html, cordova, mobile

I want to develop a mobile app for image capturing with camera, initially i wanted to use phonegap and tried downloading and installing the cordovastarter template for my visual studio2010, but all the versiosn of phonegap are giving me the error...'the project type is not supported by this installation' so want to drop the idea of using phonegap, so the next thing is, is it possible to interact with camera using by using only html5 without the help of phonegap?

note:im using mvc3 framework

Answer (score 0):

its very much posible to interact with the camera using HTML5 media API, but the support is **not** yet confirmed. Hence, might not work as you'd expect:

HTML part:

```
<video id="video" width="640" height="480" autoplay></video>
<button id="snap">Snap Photo</button>
<canvas id="canvas" width="640" height="480"></canvas>
```

and the javascript goes like this:

```
// Put event listeners into place
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
// Grab elements, create settings, etc.
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas"),
context = canvas.getContext("2d"),
video = document.getElementById("video"),
videoObj = { "video": true },
errBack = function(error) {
  console.log("Video capture error: ", error.code); 
};

// Put video listeners into place
if(navigator.getUserMedia) { // Standard
navigator.getUserMedia(videoObj, function(stream) {
  video.src = stream;
  video.play();
}, errBack);
} else if(navigator.webkitGetUserMedia) { // WebKit-prefixed
navigator.webkitGetUserMedia(videoObj, function(stream){
  video.src = window.webkitURL.createObjectURL(stream);
  video.play();
}, errBack);
}}, false);
```

Hope it helps, source [here](http://davidwalsh.name/browser-camera).